# Why can't I set an attribute to an object's array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I want to set `a[1]` name to `Gabriel` for example, and it always give me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at Register.main(Register.java:4)
```

My code is:

```java
public class Register {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee a[] = new Employee[2];
        a[0].setName("Douglas");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an array of non-primitive, you create an array of `null`s of the specified size. Before accessing the objects' properties, you need to create them (using `new`):

```
Employee a[] = new Employee[2];
a[0] = new Employee(); // Here!
a[0].setName("Douglas");
```

Answer (score 3):

We can assume that your `Employee` class is as below:

```java
class Employee {
    private String name;

    public Employee(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee a[] = null;

        if (a == null)
            System.out.println("Employee array is null !!!");

        a = new Employee[10]; // You are init your aray

        a[0] = new Employee("Test Name 1"); // it's init first item of array
        a[1] = new Employee("Test Name 2"); // it's init second item of array
        a[2] = new Employee("Test Name 3"); // it's init third item of array

        for (Employee employee : a) {
            if (employee == null) {
                System.out.println("Employee  is null !!!");
            } else
                System.out.println("Employee  is not null : "
                        + employee.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

As you see in your code `"Employee a[] = new Employee[2];"` only allocate space for count of employee. But it is set with `null`. Because it keeps your `null` employee references, so you should init them one by one. Because of this reason `"a[0].setName("Douglas");"` trying to reach null address and throws exception.

If run it you can see this output:

```
Employee array is null !!!
Employee  is not null : Test Name 1
Employee  is not null : Test Name 2
Employee  is not null : Test Name 3
Employee  is null !!!
Employee  is null !!!
Employee  is null !!!
Employee  is null !!!
Employee  is null !!!
Employee  is null !!!
Employee  is null !!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builder pattern through [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), and the list can be initialized with non-null objects.

```java
import lombok.Builder;
import org.assertj.core.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;

public static class Main {

    @Builder
    public class Employee {
        private String name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Main.Employee> employees = List.of(
                Employee.builder().name("Douglas").build(),
                Employee.builder().name("Maik").build(),
                Employee.builder().name("Alex").build()
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a constructor to the `Employee` class. Then you can create an array as follows:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Employee[] arr = {
            new Employee("Douglas"),
            new Employee("Douglas2")};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // [Douglas, Douglas2]
}
```

```java
public static class Employee {
    String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```